# WSO2 ESB cannot update configuration

Tags: java, configuration, wso2, esb, file-locking

We cannot update the configuration on a recently installed WSO2 ESB 4.8.1
Exactly the same error happens in Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2 (3 PCs tested). jre7 and jdk1.7.0_51 tested.

After install, simply pushing the "Update" button in "Service Bus Configuration" page of the Management Console (Chrome, Firefox or Explorer), even without changing anything, gives a pop-up window error "There is an error in your configuration".

ESB log informs

```
WARN - MultiXMLConfigurationSerializer Error while attempting to lock the file: registry.xml
        java.io.IOException: Access is denied
                at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method)
                at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(FileDispatcherImpl.java:86)
        ...
WARN - MultiXMLConfigurationSerializer Unable to acquire lock on file: registry.xml
WARN - MultiXMLConfigurationSerializer File: registry.xml is not writable
```

It could be "C:\esb\wso2esb-4.8.1\repository\conf\registry.xml"

We can edit the file by hand with Notepad. We even take the risk in change permissions to "everyone", but the problem remains.

Any clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your registry.xml file in the ESB, is the following set to :

```
 <readOnly>true</readOnly> ,
```

if so change to false.